# Relative positioning of nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

Consider this simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
    % Draw axes
    \draw [<->,thick] (0,2.2) node (yaxis) [above] {$t$}
        |- (2.2,0) node (xaxis) [right] {$s$};
    % Draw triangle's legs
    \draw (0.5,0.5) coordinate (a)  -- +(1.3,0) coordinate (b);
    \draw (b) -- +(0,1.5) coordinate (c);

    \draw (a) .. controls +(10:1) and +(265:1) .. (c)
    node[sloped,above,pos=0.5] {$t=g(s)$};

    % Draw vertices and labels
    \fill[red] (a) circle (1pt);
    \draw (a) node[left] {$a$};
    \fill[red] (b) circle (1pt);
    \draw (b) node[right] {$b$};
    \fill[red] (c) circle (1pt);
    \draw (c) node[right] {$c$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to position a fourth point `d` relative to one of the other points. I want it to be a standalone coordinate, such that later in the code I could refer to it. For example, have `\draw (d) -- (0,0);` or something similar.

Thanks!

Comment: A little late perhaps, but for the benefit of people only coming across this now, definitely check out the TikZ library `positioning` (see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69439/how-can-i-achieve-relative-positioning-in-tikz)).

Comment: @Casimir thank you so much for this link! Exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This can be done using the following ways:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
% ...

\coordinate (d) at ($ (c) + (1,3) $);
```

or

```
\path (c) ++(1,3) coordinate (d);
```

The latter one might add a invisible path to your picture, which should not be an issue most of the time.

Comment: I can confirm that both approached solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Note that in the first case one can also subtract, in the other option one has to add a negative number, for example `(c) ++(-1,3)`.

Comment: @Dror: Yes, the `++` is a fixed syntax, there is no `--`, so you have to use negative numbers.