# Move a tikz node somewhat below in relative positioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I have the following code (stripped down from a much larger one).

*(I understand that there are numerous questions (and answers including [this excellent one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80322/14103)) on relative positioning of nodes, but they do not seem to solve my problem. Before you mark my question as duplicate, please make it sure that it really addresses my issue ie. use relative positioning and not absolute positioning.)*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=40.0mm, auto]
  \node[state] (3) {3}; 
  \node[state] (1) [above left=of 3]  {1}; 
  \node[state] (2) [above right=of 3] {2}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this.

[image]

I would like to move node 3 somewhat below its current position. I have tried 
many ways of doing this using relative positioning (and without using absolute 
positioning), without success. How do I do this?

Comment: Is a `\node (1) [above left=5cm and 1cm of 3] {1};` satisfying your problem? This way you can set the `above` and the `left`|`right` individually from each other.

Comment: @moospit Afraid not. I have already seen those answers. I am somewhat determined (perhaps for no reason), to achieve the effect using relative positioning only.

Comment: As you are using `\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=40.0mm]`, would it be a solution to different to horizontal and vertical node spacing using `\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=40.0mm and 2cm]`? (2nd value is vertical spacing)

Comment: @moospit Yes, that is acceptable since you do not have to carry out manual positioning for every node you put in.

Comment: For this kind of diagrams, a `tikz` `matrix` approach is more suitable where you can declare row separation and column separation in the beginning itself.

Comment: @HarishKumar Care to elaborate a little more? Or better yet, why not post a complete answer with your approach. Despite my twenty five years of experience with LaTeX, my experience with tikz is less than twenty five days.

Comment: @HarishKumar  I would like those sample codes, or as I said, would like more solution to my problem with the matrix approach you suggested.

Comment: Masroor, I have added some sample code. Sorry for the delay as my internet is very slow.

Comment: Masroor, close this question by selecting an answer ...

Comment: @RicardoCruz Eventually, I used neither of the answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Just to sum up the above comments and get future readers an overview about the discussed answers:

**Prerequisites**:

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
```

**Per node** distance definition:

```
\node (id) [below left=<x-value> and <y-value> of <reference>] {<text>};
```

**Global** distance definition:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=<x-value> and <y-value>]
 \node (id) [below left=of <reference>] {<text>};
 % ...
```

Comment: Note that this code requires the `positioning` tikz library.

Answer (score 7):

For this kind of diagrams where you are putting many nodes relative to one another, a `matrix` approach would be more suited. You have to use `\usetikzlibrary{matrix}` and declare the nodes as the elements of a matrix. The row and column separations, node styles etc can be declared via `\tikzset`. You can refer to those nodes using the name of the matrix say (m) like `(m-1-1)` where `(m-2-3)`  2 is the row and 3 is the column (indices).

Here is a sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,automata}   %% load the library

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{   %%% define the parameters for once
    mstyle/.style={column sep=4cm, row sep=6cm,nodes={state},font=\bfseries},
    line/.style={draw,very thick,blue,-latex},
  }
  \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&,mstyle]{
    1 \&  \& 2  \\
      \& 3 \&   \\
    4 \& 5 \& 6  \\
  };
    \draw[line](m-1-1.east)-- (m-1-3.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `row sep = 2cm` in `\mstyle`, we get

[image]

And with our very technique `\\[2cm]`, we get

```
\matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&,mstyle]{
    1 \&  \& 2  \\[2cm]
      \& 3 \&   \\
    4 \& 5 \& 6  \\
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to `pgfmanual`, page no 654 (in my copy of v3) section 57.

However, I accept that I am not aware of how your final diagram will be. Hence, you are the better judge of choices you have.