# Is there a way to plot tikz things easier?

Tags: tikz-pgf

It may look too broad, but each time I want to draw something using tikz, it turns just into the hell, cause I always have to keep in mind all the coordinates I want. Well, for the square like this

```
\draw (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
```

Thats not a problem, but for complicated things it is really difficult. Is not there a way to easier the work?

Comment: You can give the coordinates names and refer to the names instead of the numerical vector.

Comment: If you show an example someone may find some hacks to improve the code clarity.

Comment: Do you know the `positioning` library? See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69439 for example. There you can use `\node[above right] (AnotherNode) {Text};`

Comment: BTW, you should use `cycle` instead of repeating the last point, although the reason shows up better with acute triangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only two coordinates...

```
\draw (1,1) rectangle (3,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are (selection):

- macro definitions
- lengths, counters,
- named coordinates,
- pics,
- ...

For example:

```
\newcommand*{\MyLengthOfSquare}{4}
\draw
  (0, 0) coordinate (MyLowerLeftCornerOfSquare)
  rectangle (\MySquareLength, \MySquareLength)
  coordinate (MyUpperRightCornerOfSquare)
;
```

The named coordinates `MyLowerLeftCornerOfSquare` and `MyUpperRightCornerOfSquare` can then be used in the
following TikZ commands.