# Node position TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like make something like the pic below, but in horizontal format. How do I get the text boxes equidistant between susceptible and exposed? [Relative positioning of nodes in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15701/relative-positioning-of-nodes-in-tikz) uses coordinates. Isn't there a way to do with relative to an object?

[image]

```
   \documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,
backgrounds,fit,positioning,shapes.symbols,chains}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}


\begin{document}



% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!30,
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
%\tikzstyle{curve}=[draw,(latex']


\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance =4cm, auto,
comment/.style={
rectangle, 
inner sep= 5pt, 
text width=4cm, }]


    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (susceptible) {Susceptible};
    \node [block, right of=susceptible] (exposed) {Exposed};


\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=0pt,yshift=0pt]
 (3.8,-2)--(-1,-2)  node [black,midway,yshift=-0.6cm] 
{ \emph{Environmental \& Human factors} 
};


    \node [block, right of=exposed] (infectious) {Infectious};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=0pt,yshift=0pt]
(7.9,-2) -- (4.1,-2)  node [black,midway,yshift=-0.6cm] 
{ \emph{Variable immunity} };




   \node [block, right of=infectious] (removed) {Removed};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=0pt,yshift=0pt]
(12,-2) -- (8.2,-2)  node [black,midway,yshift=-0.6cm] 
{ \emph{Control parameters} };


\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=0pt,yshift=0pt]
(0.1,1) -- (3.9,1) node [black,midway,yshift=0.6cm] 
{\large  Contact parameters};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},xshift=0pt,yshift=0pt]
(4.1,1) -- (12,1) node [black,midway,yshift=0.6cm] 
{\large  Disease parameters};


    \path [line] (susceptible) -- (exposed);
    \path [line] (exposed) -- (infectious);
    \path [line] (infectious) -- (removed);

\path[line,dashed] (removed.south) -- + (0,-.35) -- + (-12,-.35) -- (susceptible.south);


\end{tikzpicture}}
\smallskip
\label{fig:flowchart_disease_transmission}
\caption{Flowchart of fundamental disease transmission mechanisms}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
Looks like this and took me 2 hours (looks okay-ish):

[image]
In powerpoint, 5 mins but looks pants!

Still can't work out how to get an itemized list in the lower braces.

Comment: Look pgf/tikz manual for "`chains`" examples. Also [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/chains/)

Comment: Is it not possible without chains?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were almost there! I just want to suggest some changes to your code.

Don't use fixed coordinates if you can use relative ones. As an example, you say

```
\path[line,dashed] (removed.south) -- + (0,-.35) -- + (-12,-.35) -- (susceptible.south);
```

because you know distance between `removed` and `susceptible` nodes, but if you change `node distance` will have to also modify this line (and all `braces`). It's better to use

```
\draw [line,dashed] (removed.south) -- ++ (0,-.35) -| (susceptible.south);
```

which means, "draw a dashed line from `removed.south` to a point .35cm below it, move there and draw a rectangular corner from this point to `susceptible.south`".

For all your `braces` you can use something like:

```
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=3mm}]
    (susceptible.85) -- (exposed.95) 
    node [black,midway,yshift=6mm] {\large  Contact parameters};
```

`raise` option moves `brace` up from reference points which are now `susceptible.85` and `exposed.95`. This means a point on nodes border at angle 85.

For braces below blocks you can use `mirror` option and you won't have to change nodes order.

```
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=6mm, mirror}]
      (susceptible.275)--(exposed.265)  
      node  [black,midway,yshift=-1cm,text width=3cm, align=center,anchor=north] (EHF)
     {\emph{Environmental \\ \& Human factors}};
```

From previous line, you can see I've splitted headers form lists. May be it's not too much nice but it can help to place them.

Text in nodes is something like a `parbox` if you fix some `text width`, so you can use `itemized` lists, or just set an `alignment` option. You will find two examples in next code.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,
backgrounds,fit,positioning,shapes.symbols,chains}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!30,
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance =4cm, auto,
comment/.style={
rectangle, 
inner sep= 5pt, 
text width=4cm, }]

    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (susceptible) {Susceptible};
    \node [block, right of=susceptible] (exposed) {Exposed};
    \node [block, right of=exposed] (infectious) {Infectious};
    \node [block, right of=infectious] (removed) {Removed};

    \draw [line] (susceptible) -- (exposed);
    \draw [line] (exposed) -- (infectious);
    \draw [line] (infectious) -- (removed);

     \draw [line,dashed] (removed.south) -- ++ (0,-.35) -| (susceptible.south);

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=3mm}]
(susceptible.85) -- (exposed.95) node [black,midway,yshift=6mm] 
{\large  Contact parameters};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=3mm},xshift=0pt,yshift=0pt]
(exposed.85) -- (removed.95) node [black,midway,yshift=6mm] 
{\large  Disease parameters};


\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=6mm, mirror}]
 (susceptible.275)--(exposed.265)  node  [black,midway,yshift=-1cm,text width=3cm, align=center,anchor=north] (EHF)
{ \emph{Environmental \\\& Human factors} 
};

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=6mm, mirror}]
(exposed.275) -- (infectious.265)  node (VI) [black,midway,yshift=-1.5cm] 
{ \emph{Variable immunity} };

\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt,raise=6mm, mirror}]
(infectious.275) -- (removed.265) node (CP) [black,midway,yshift=-1.5cm] 
{ \emph{Control parameters} };

\node [text width=4.5cm, align=left, anchor=north, below=1mm of EHF] {Bioaerosol load\\
Surface pathogen loading\\
Surface contact probability}; 

\node [text width=3.5cm, align=left, anchor=north, below=1mm of CP] {\begin{itemize}
\item Detection
\item Quarantine\end{itemize}}; 

\end{tikzpicture}}
\smallskip
\label{fig:flowchart_disease_transmission}
\caption{Flowchart of fundamental disease transmission mechanisms}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The final result is:

[image]

Comment: Just exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much for explaining the different options too! Very helpful! How long did you take to learn tikz? A flowchart and this picture took me 6 hours today... And that's 6 hours not writing my phd!

Comment: Out of curiosity if I wanted to make a `curve` or arc between `removed`and `susceptible` instead of the dotted line, is it a simple operation or would I have to define angles and coordinates etc?

Comment: @user1134241 `[rounded corners]` would not be enough? Or replace `--` by `to[bend left]`

Comment: @user1134241 as JLDiaz suggested `to[bend left]` is the easiest option. You can even fix bending angle with `to[bend left=10]`.

Comment: @user1134241 Every day I learn something new about `TikZ`. I think you should read `tutorials` chapters from `TikZ's` manual. They provide a lot of information in an instructive and funny style.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could write `node_name.<deg>` like you can for `north`, `south`, etc.  Can you tell me where this is in the documentation?

Comment: @A.Ellett: In Manual for 2.10 version, you will find in "13.2.3 Node Coordinate System", pages 127-129. In CVS version, pages are 132-134.

Answer (score 5):

I cleaned a bit your code by using styles. Also used the anchors of the boxes to position the braces, instead of absolute coordinates. Also, introduced the option `text width` for the bottom labels, and this allows you to use `imtemize` in their contents:

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning,arrows}

% Define some styles
\tikzset{
 block/.style = {
    rectangle, draw, fill=blue!30,
    text width=5em, 
    text centered, 
    rounded corners, 
    minimum height=4em},
 line/.style = {
    draw, -latex'},
 my brace/.style = {
   decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},
   shorten >=3pt, shorten <=3pt
 },
 bottom label/.style = {
    black, midway, yshift=-3ex, font=\itshape,
    text width = 3cm, text centered,
 },
 top label/.style = {
    black, midway, above, yshift=3ex, font=\large,
 },
}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering\makebox[\textwidth]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance =4cm, auto]

    % Place nodes
    \node [block]                       (susceptible) {Susceptible};
    \node [block, right of=susceptible] (exposed)     {Exposed};
    \node [block, right of=exposed]     (infectious)  {Infectious};
    \node [block, right of=infectious]  (removed)     {Removed};

\coordinate[below=8mm of susceptible] (bottom brace);

\draw [my brace]
      (exposed.south|-bottom brace) -- (susceptible.south west|-bottom brace) 
      node[bottom label] {
        Environmental \& Human factors
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Foo
        \item Bar
        \item Foobar
        \end{itemize}
      };

\draw [my brace]
    (infectious.south|-bottom brace) -- (exposed.south|-bottom brace)
    node [bottom label] { Variable immunity };

\draw [my brace]
    (removed.south east|-bottom brace) -- (infectious.south|-bottom brace)
    node [bottom label] { 
      Control parameters 
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Foo
        \item Bar
        \end{itemize}
     };    

\coordinate[above=3mm of susceptible] (top brace);

\draw [my brace] 
    (susceptible.north|-top brace) -- (exposed.north|-top brace)
    node [top label] {Contact parameters};

\draw [my brace]
    (exposed.north|-top brace) -- (removed.north|-top brace)
    node[top label] {Disease parameters};

\draw[line] (susceptible) -- (exposed)
            (exposed) -- (infectious)
            (infectious) -- (removed);

\path[line,dashed] 
   (removed.south) -- +(0,-.35) -| (susceptible.south);

\end{tikzpicture}}
\smallskip
\label{fig:flowchart_disease_transmission}
\caption{Flowchart of fundamental disease transmission mechanisms}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Result]